# How can i send a push notification?

Tags: objective-c, xml, push-notification

i'm trying to add push notification to my app, but, so far, i could find only tutorial that seems to be old and outdated... Can someone explain me how can i make my app send a notification?

My app takes some content from an xml online and i want to send the notification when the xml contains a date of update more recent. Can i?

Comment: APNS mechanism does not change much since its release. You can still use the mechanism in old tutorials.

Comment: good to know. maybe you can point me one that is a good choice?

Comment: This is the Best Link I know for Push Notifications
Its **Simple and Clear** http://blog.serverdensity.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Comment: some "answers" below points you to good resources, where http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 is the best (in my opinion).

Comment: i know the second, he taught me how to do the provisioning procedure! I'll try the two and make you know if i could manage the notification! Thank you very much!

Comment: can i ask you why your answer turned into comments? i cannot choose one in this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple and clear video about this here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3YlqWWnI6s.
It is simple and clear, and after that i followed http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 and http://blog.serverdensity.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/. So i managed to send push notification. Needs some work but it's not do difficult as i thought.